# NGINX SSL Termination for TCP Upstream Servers and Pass TLS Session details upstream

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Using nginx/1.14.0 with conf file as listed below... My NGINX terminates the TLS ingress session and successfully passes the TCP upstream. I would like to obtain TLS session details within my upstream TCP backend server... Is there a config option or something else that I can use to obtain TLS session details like ssl_client_i_dn, ssl_server_name, ssl_session_id, etc? I need this information within the backend server, but the TLS termination is being done within NGINX.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream{
    upstream tcp_be {
    server backend1.example.com:12345;
}

server {
    listen              12345 ssl;

    proxy_pass          tcp_be;

    ssl_certificate     /opt/certs/mytest.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/certs/mytest.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout   4h;
    ssl_handshake_timeout 30s;
}
```